# force:refreshView not refreshing Related List - Single

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, related-list, lightning-community

On a record detail page for communities (created in Builder) we have a few custom Lightning Components as well as a few `Related List - Single` standard components.

One of the `Related List - Single` components is pointing to a junction object between this record and some other object (call it `ChildObject__c`). One of our component is a list of `ChildObject__c` records that the user might want to add to that related list, i.e. create a new junction object.

That component allows the user to select one of those records and create a new junction object. We can do all that programmatically and it is helpful to the user.

The problem is that there is no way to refresh the contents of the `Related List - Single`. So in effect, the user creates these new junction objects and links their parent record to these `ChildObject__c` records, but there is no visible indication that that actually happened, short of hitting F5.

I tried to call `$A.get("e.force:refreshView")` on the callback from creating the record. That does refresh the page, we see the three dots spinner and the other components reload themselves, but the `Related List - Single` components do not. They sit there adamantly displaying their old cached data.

Is this a bug in `force:refreshView`? Is it designed to work that way (being called from a related list, but not update a related list)? Is there a better way to force a related list to retrieve data?

Comment: Have you raised a case with SF support?

Comment: SIGH. Yes, I raised a case with SF support. That makes 5 currently open cases I have with SF support about Lightning Components. If I get a satisfactory answer I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got a concrete answer from Support.
It's an ongoing bug with Salesforce, and as much as I pressed the support reps, there is no hint as to when (if ever) this will be resolved.
The workaround presented in the issue is a non-starter for us, so we're really stuck here.

[Link to issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDOuQAM).